# SQL Server scheduled stored procedure was working, but now runs very slowly

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, job-scheduling, logfile, shrink

We have a stored procedure being called by a daily job schedule that used to work within a reasonable time frame but is now performing very badly and failing. Whatever the cause, it seems to also be bogging down our whole system. We tried rebooting the computer, but the problem persisted.

The stored procedure acts as an ETL to import data from one database to another and make some updates. When called from the job, it used to run within an hour, but then about 7 days ago it started taking 10-15 hours to run. Then the last 3 days it has failed altogether. Today I let it run for 10 hours and then cancelled it.

The error message for the failed runs found it was failing because the log file is out of space. So I tried to shrink the log file by using the code below. It worked, but it didn't reduce the file size at all. Since the code didn't work, I tried shrinking using SSMS, but that failed due to the error:

> Lock request time out period exceeded

I ran `sp_who2` and, without knowing for sure (I'm a developer not a DBA), found the following which seemed relevant:

> SPID: 63, Status: Suspended, Command: Delete, CPU Time: 1142382, DiskIO: 1254258

I thought that could be the issue so I tried to end that transaction using `Kill 63`. However, it appears that didn't work because if I run `sp_who2` it now reads

> SPID: 63, Status: Suspended, Command: Killed/Rollback, CPU Time: 1142803, DiskIO: 1261601

Any help to resolve the issue would be appreciated! Specifically:

1. Any ideas what could be causing the bad performance all of a sudden?
2. How can I shrink the log file?  Could that be causing the bad performance?

Here's the code I tried:

```
USE MyDatabase;
GO

ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
GO

DBCC SHRINKFILE (MyDatabase_log, 1);
GO

ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase
SET RECOVERY FULL;
GO
```

Comment: Although there are many people with DB knowledge here on SO, you might have better luck asking on [dba.se] as that site is might be more focused on non-developments related aspects.

Comment: The information you gave is not much helpfull..Please post execution plan of stored proc.also try updating statistics of the objects involved in stored proc...post your  sql version.Most importantly look here and see how to ask and get help fast.Even though its  a tsql format,try to understand the essence..https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: You need to see if there was any growth in data that is associated with your queries.  Also, looking at "long running queries" you may be able to see some trends - or at least run them (if they are reading data) and then monitor your server stats and underlying hardware.

Comment: `Lock request time out` - that's not _slow running_ - that means someone else locked data your script needs and does not release it for a long time.

Comment: And about recovery model: option 1 - you say that shrinking log is okay; option 2 - you need full recovery model. If you need `full` - you may not shrinking log and switching back and forth from simple to full. If you don't need log - choose `simple` model and don't change it.

Comment: Okay. Been trying all your  suggestions. So far was able to shrink the log file but it has grown back. I will switch to simple mode to see if that works. I also ran execution plans but there are a lot of queries involved so not sure how I would bring all that here and have it be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a hard disk problem.  Initially the hardware team insisted it was not, but after further testing and reviews it in fact was a bad disk.